Error with ExecuteUpdateAsync in Entity Framework Core 8.0.0 with ASP.NET Core 8 Web API
I am encountering an issue while using the ExecuteUpdateAsync feature of Entity Framework Core v8.0.0 in an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project.
The error message I receive is as follows:

This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.ZombieCheck()
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Commit()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTransaction.Commit()

Here are the code details :
private async Task DemoUpdateTestTable(DemoReq demoReq, IEnumerable<string>? toUpdateMailList, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await _demoDbContext.TestTable
        .Where(recordsToUpdate => toUpdateMailList.Contains(recordsToUpdate.EmailAddress) && 
                                  recordsToUpdate.Id == demoReq.Id)
        .ExecuteUpdateAsync(setters => setters
            .SetProperty(r => r.ModifyUserId, demoReq.CreateUserId)
            .SetProperty(r => r.ModifyDate, demoReq.ModifyDate)
            .SetProperty(r => r.IsApproved, r => r.IsApproved != true ? null : (bool?)null),
        cancellationToken);
}

Can anyone help me here with some code sample which will serve as a reference for my implementation?

Do you have a [mre]? Can you please add a full stack trace?

The error message indicates a transaction issue, could you pls share a complete code sample containing how you manage the transaction? According to the error message, you are doing an SqlTransaction operation when the SqlTransaction already commit or rollback. So that we might need to make sure for example we proper handle asynchronous methods, and something related else.

Thanks @TinyWang for your response.  I call the above method from an action method. Here I am using ExecuteUpdateAsync method from EntityFramework Core with version 8.0.0. Apart from that nothing else I am using in this case

Thank you for your reply and could you pls share a minimal sample for reproducing the issue just like  @GuruStron said? Based on the current code snippet I think we are not able to troubleshoot it as your code and logic looks good.
